# skipping login screen in appdelegate not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, rootviewcontroller

I am trying to skip the login screen in appdelegate and i am using world known method of assigning the next view controller to rootviewcontroller but somehow it's not working for testing purposes I have not set any condition and this code is directly executed but doesn't reflect in the app.

> my loginViewController is embedded in navigationController

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homepage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController") as! mainTabBarController
self.window?.rootViewController = homepage
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**I have gone through a lot so answers for this but they are suggesting the same method.**

*"comment for extra info on the question"*.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?
In Xcode 11 things changed a bit.

Comment: Please show all of the code in your AppDelegate. Can you get any viewController to show?

Comment: @DoesData yes give me a minute

Comment: @DungeonDev its Xcode 11.2.1

Comment: You must do your logic in scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) of SceneDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using Xcode 11 and above**

1. Delete `SceneDelegate.swift`
2. Delete `UISceneSession Lifecycle` methods from `AppDelegate`
3. Add `var window: UIWindow?` in `AppDelegate` class
4. Open `Info.plist` and delete `Application Scene Manifest`
5. Add the below line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)     
self.window?.rootViewController = //...
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I have tried that but it seems it's not working but I will try one more time.

Comment: @NickCoder If you are using Xcode 11 and above you should delete `SceneDelegate` and `UISceneSession Lifecycle` methods from app delegate

Comment: Thanks the real issue was those step